# One toolbar, multiple textarea's

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a setup where I have multiple textfields/textarea's that are editable but I want the toolbar of the kendoEditor on a fixed place and not floating above the textarea's. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the so called inline editing mode. Check it out [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/editor/inline-editing.html). It is pretty cool imo :)